# Excitations of the string-net Hamiltonian

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, category-theory

A quite general 2D topological order can be constructed through the [string-net theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404617). Here, if the input data is some braided fusion category $C$ (i.e. the $F$-symbols), the elementary excitations are simple objects of the Drinfeld center $Z(C)$.

My question is: for a string-net theory, where the input data is not a braided fusion category (as in the case of toric code), are the excitations still the Drinfeld center?

Comment: My understanding was that the in general string-net models take spherical fusion categories as inputs. What is the more general notion of a string-net model?

Comment: @d_b, Right! My question is: given any spherical fusion category as an input, are the excitations of the corresponding string-net model the Drinfeld center?

Comment: Sorry, I realize I misread your question. I believe this is answered affirmatively in Kirillov Jr's nice paper *String-net model of Turaev-Viro invariants* here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.6033

Comment: @d_b Ah! I see! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Why do you talk about ground states?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned it at all. It's a piece of background that I had in mind. I have modified my question.